# How to get the outside world to see Windows Server 2008 R2 web sites?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, dyndns

Newbie, so bear with me here, but I'm looking to install Windows Server on a VM at home.  I'd like to make the websites visible to the outside world via IIS.  How do I go about doing this?

I'm aware that DynDNS will help me to create a URL that constantly points to the right IP.  From there I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to open port 80 in your device that you use to connect to the internet.

Comment: ... and point it to the IP of the Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are doing DynDNS you have the IP updater installed either on the firewall or or on the server (you would be surprised how many people miss that).